# How to match date in aggregate $match using MongoDB and Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I have more than 50 thousand records in mongodb collections. To avoid foreach loop in laravel I am using aggregate in my query.

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-10-01 00:00:00"));
$result = Pms::raw(function ($collection) use($start){
        return $collection->aggregate(array(
            array( '$project' => array( 'EventTS' => 1, 'MainsPower' => 1, '_id' => 0) ),
            array(
                '$unwind' => array(
                    'path' => '$MainsPower',
                    'includeArrayIndex' => "arrayIndex",
                    'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
                )
            ),
            array(
                '$match' => array(
                    'EventTS' => array(
                        '$gte' => $start
                    )
                )
            ),                
            array(
                '$project' => array(
                    'MainsPower' => 1,
                    'timestamp' => array(
                        '$add' => array(
                            '$EventTS',
                            array( '$multiply' => array( 60000, '$arrayIndex' ) )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
    })->toArray();
```

I need to compare date with a collection, but if I use below code then my result set returns empty.

```
 array(
            '$match' => array(
                'EventTS' => array(
                    '$gte' => $start
                )
            )
        )
```

what's the right way to **compare date** in mongodb collection inside PHP with Laravel 5.2.

Attached is the Sample Document

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("576165f58d8b8f39458b456a"), 
    "EventTS" : ISODate("2000-05-11T05:30:00.000+0000"), 
    "PanelID" : "A01000", 
    "MainsPower" : [
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        NumberInt(147), 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null
    ], 
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("576165f58d8b8f39458b456b"), 
    "EventTS" : ISODate("2016-06-08T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
    "PanelID" : "A01604", 
    "MainsPower" : [
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/)'s **[`createFromDate()`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/tests/Carbon/CreateFromDateTest.php)** property to create the date range since Laravel also supports [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) or `DateTime` objects instead of MongoDate objects which will be converted internally to MongoDate objects when saved to the database.

In the same breadth as above, you would want to restructure your aggregation operation so that the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** filter is first in the pipeline, before the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operation, that way you can optimize your aggregation operation as `EventsTS` is an independent field from the `MainsPower` array (at least from the way the code was written).

Also, you won't need the initial project operator, not necessary as further down the pipeline you have another **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator which is returning just the required fields.

So, applying the [**`Carbon`**](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) package, you can try the following pipeline:

```
$start = Carbon::createFromDate(2015, 10, 1);
$result = Pms::raw(function ($collection) use($start){
        return $collection->aggregate(array(
            array(
                '$match' => array(
                    'EventTS' => array(
                        '$gte' => $start
                    )
                )
            ), 
            array(
                '$unwind' => array(
                    'path' => '$MainsPower',
                    'includeArrayIndex' => "arrayIndex",
                    'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
                )
            ),                           
            array(
                '$project' => array(
                    'MainsPower' => 1,
                    'timestamp' => array(
                        '$add' => array(
                            '$EventTS',
                            array( '$multiply' => array( 60000, '$arrayIndex' ) )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
    })->toArray();
```

Comment: I followed your instructions. I removed the initial projection and moved the match query before the unwind. I also tried copy pasting your code but i still get an empty set.@chridam

Comment: One way you can debug a pipeline that's giving you unexpected results is to run the aggregation with just the first pipeline operator. If that gives the expected result, add the next. In the answer above, you'd first try aggregating just the `$match`; if that works, add the `$unwind`. This can help you narrow down which operator is causing issues. If the issue is with the `$match` operator then try changing the date variables in the range query, see if some dates match.

Comment: We tried debugging one element at a time. It seems that any date operation on the query is failing using the above method. It works fine for string and integer comparison. We tried all operators for data comparison and all of them return an empty set. @chridam

Comment: By the way, can you edit your question by providing some sample documents that can be used to replicate the same issue as above?

Comment: uploaded a couple of sample documents.

Comment: I tried laravel whereDate() but return an empty set

Comment: Thanks @chridam finally working i make some changes in code